# Show that $y = (r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n, 0, 0, \dots)$ is countable.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

While proving that the space $l^p$ with $1 \le p < \infty$ is separable, the book is suggested the following subset [which is easy to prove denseness...] :

> $M$ to be the set of all sequences $y$ of the form $y = (r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n, 0, 0, \dots)$ where $n$ is any positive integer and the $r_j$'s are rational.

How to prove that $M$ is countable? $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Q^i}$ 'looks' big enough to be like $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ than finitely many product of $\mathbb{Q}$ to be countable.

I am not much familiar with axiomatic set theory. Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: $M$ seems to be the set of all infinite sequence with rational entries in which all but a finite number of entries (almost all) are 0.

Comment: @Wuestenfux, for any integer n means that n approaches infinity?

Comment: No what I meant is that each sequence has only a finite number of nonzero entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M$ is countable, because

$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}^i\right|
&\leq\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|\mathbb{Q}|^i\\
&=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\aleph_0^i\\
&=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\aleph_0\\
&=\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0
\end{align*}
$$

Or, a bit more concretely, fix a bijection $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{N}$, $f(0)=0$ and inject $M\to\mathbb{N}$ by $2^{f(r_1)}\cdot 3^{f(r_2)}\cdot 5^{f(r_3)}\cdots$

Comment: I know that a finite product of countable sets is countable. But I don't understand how that holds when n goes to infinity.

Comment: You only have countable union of finite product, not the full countable product.  For example, (1,1/2,1/4,1/8,....) is not in the set $M$ but is in the "too large" space of $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ (indeed, this space includes sequences that isn't bounded so not in $\ell_p$ for any $p$).

Comment: I mean that because n goes to infinity so there are **'eventually'** sequences that has no zero in it. So we can't apply "a **finite** product of countable sets is countable" theorem. So (1,1/2,1/4,1/8,....) **is** in the set M?

Comment: No!  For each $n$, the set of all $(r_1,\dots,r_n,0,\dots)$ is countable (finite product of countables).  Now take countable union over all $n$ and that is your $M$.  $M$ only contains those sequences that are eventually $0$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much. (infinity always looks with full of paradoxes)

Answer (score 0):

$A_n=$

{$(r_1,r_2,..,r_n,0,0,..)|$

$ r_i \in \mathbb{Q}, 1\le i \le n$}.

Consider

$f: A_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^n, $

$f(r_1,r_2,...,r_n,0,0,..) =$

$ (r_1,r_2,...r_n)$  is a bijection.

Since $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable $A_n$ is countable.

The countable union of countable sets

${\displaystyle \cup}_n A_n$ is countable.